# How to prevent a semicolon from being entered into html text input, but allowing a colon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ascii, keycode

I want to allow input such as 1:10, but not 1;10. However, : and ; both correspond to keyCode 186, so using keyCode to prevent the ; key from inputting into my input field does not work. I also researched into using charCodes, but charCodes don't have the ; or : values. Finally, I looked at ascii tables. They have semicolon and colon values. Is there any way for me to possibly use ascii tables to prevent the ; key from inputting into my textbox, but the : key to be allowed? Or is there another approach that will let me do this? I also thought about detecting two key inputs in a row, so that I could detect a shift key input, but that seems like a dirty solution.

```
 $("input.form-1").bind({
    keydown: function(e) {
        if(e.which ===186) { //trying to disallow semicolons, which also disallows colons
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try checking `shiftKey` is down or not

Comment: They both correspond to keyCode 186 on an US-International or US-English keyboard. There are a lot of other keyboard layouts out there. These will probably not work correctly with this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Rory said, you should be using `on`.  Instead of checking the shiftKey, you can also just check the `key` property on the event. [MDN KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

```js
$("input.form-1").on({
    keydown: function(e) {
        if(e.key === ";") { // disallow semicolon
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-1" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use `bind()`. It was deprecated a *long* time ago. Use `on()` instead.

To fix your issue you need to detect if the `shift` key is held down, for which you can use the `shiftKey` property of the event:

```js
$("input.form-1").on({
  keydown: function(e) {
    if (!e.shiftKey && e.which === 186) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-1" type="text" />
```

Comment: I think it will be `!e.shiftKey` because `:` will come when `shiftKey` is down, what he wants to allow!

Comment: I suppose this assumes a conventional querty-ish keyboard.  Are the semi-colon and colon always these same keystrokes in every country?

Comment: @BuhBuh I'm not certain without testing it, but you're correct in that it is a concern if multi-lingual support is required. I'd suggest using @SvenTheSurfer's `event.key` method in that case, assuming you don't need to support older versions of IE.

Comment: In Europe, a lot of national keyboard layouts have special chars like `:` and `;` on a different location.

Comment: I liked the accepted solution a bit better since it didn't use shiftKey. Thanks for the help though. Your answer was also good.

Comment: Glad to help. Just be aware that `event.key` isn't available in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

You just try `e.keycode` the keycode for `:`58 and `;` 59. if you want any keycode for letter or Symbols you just type within text below mention code.

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" size="40" onkeypress="myFunction(event)">

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction(event) {
    var x =  event.keyCode;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that the keyCode is different here as you're using an outdated `on*` event attribute - which is a bad idea in itself. In an unobtrusive handler or jQuery the keycode is 186 (https://jsfiddle.net/5u8czo29/) as the OP correctly used

Comment: Are there multiple definitions of keyCode for each type of event handler? I see some people using 59 as the keyCode for ; and others using 186

Answer (score 0):

Check the keycode and key both in if condition.

```
$("input.form-1").on({
    keydown: function(e) {
        if(e.key === ";") { // disallow semicolon
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why check both?  You don't trust `e.key === ";"`  ?